# CSS can't align button

Tags: css

It seems I have a PHP function that echoes out a button (which is a mixture of a and img) whenever I don't have a session. This is added inside my top-menu-container which is a div. I'd like to pull this button all the way to the right and align it in the middle; however, as I use float:right; it interferes with my vertical menu making it go a bit down leaving a gap, this menu is very simple as it was taken from w3school tutorial I only did minor changes such as adding a i tag in order to add icons from FontAwesome. This vertical menu does not belong to my top-menu-container.

In a nutshell, I'd like my login button to be added all the way to the right without interfering with my vertical menu.

I'd also take and appreciate some tips from more experienced users!

```css
    body {
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url("../resources/bkg.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 60px;
    line-height: 200%;
}
.top-menu-container {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

#login{
    float:right;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    position: fixed; /* Make it stick, even on scroll */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scrolling if the sidenav has too much content */
    text-align: center;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-weight: bold;

}
li a.withdrawal {
    color: #27ae60;
}

li a.logout {
    color: #27ae60;
}
li a.withdrawal {
    color: #27ae60;
}
li a.withdrawal {
    color: #27ae60;
}
/* Change the link color on hover */
li a:hover {
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    color: white;
}
li a:hover {
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/main.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<body>
    <div class="top-menu-container">
    <div id="login">
        <a href='?login'><img src='https://war-lords.net/images/wl/signin_steam.png' style='width:160px;height='60px'></a>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="vertical-menu-container">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="jackpot" href="#">Jackpot</a></li>
            <li><a class="withdrawal" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bolt" style="font-size: 20px;color:#27ae60"></i>  Deposit</a></li>
            <li><a class="support" href="#">Support</a></li>
            <li><a class='logout' href='?logout'><i class='fa fa-wrench' style='font-size: 20px;color:#27ae60'></i>  Log out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes please add the HTML and CSS that you have currently.

Comment: Without the source code it is hard to suggest a solution.

Comment: done! code has been added :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your vertical menu's `<ul>` currently has `position: fixed` applied to it. This means that it's always going to stay in that position when the page is being scrolled or moved around.

Therefore, you can apply some absolute positioning to it. If you add `top: 0;` to the `<ul>` element it will attach itself to the page at the very top.

The full CSS for your `<ul>` element would therefore look like this:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    position: fixed; /* Make it stick, even on scroll */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scrolling if the sidenav has too much content */
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
}
```

As an aside, you may want to check your CSS over. You've got some duplicate tags (two `<ul>`'s) and a few other invalid or unneeded properties lying around.

Comment: thanks again jack! It's very kind of you to help me out

Answer (score 0):

try `display:right;` instead of `float:right;`

Comment: #login{
 display:right;
} -- / I tried this, didn't work :[

Comment: [`right` isn't a valid option for `display`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Answer (score 0):

I found a kind of dumb solution but it works put the top-menu-container div before the vertical-menu-container div because the vertical-menu-container is taking the whole width of the window that's why there's a gap 
here's the result [image]